# Add projection to rioxarray dataset in Python

Tags: python, netcdf, rioxarray, xarray

I've downloaded a netcdf from the Climate Data Store and would like to write a CRS to it, so I can clip it for a shapefile. However, I get an error when assigning a CRS. Below my script and what is being printed. I receive this error after trying to write a crs:

MissingSpatialDimensionError: y dimension (lat) not found. Data variable: lon_bnds

```
# load netcdf with xarray
dset = xr.open_dataset(netcdf_fn)
print(dset)

# add projection system to nc
dset = dset.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)

# mask CMIP6 data with shapefile
dset_shp = dset.rio.clip(shp.geometry.apply(mapping), shp.crs)

dset
Out[44]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 1825, bnds: 2, lat: 2, lon: 1)
Coordinates:
  * time         (time) object 2021-01-01 12:00:00 ... 2025-12-31 12:00:00
  * lat          (lat) float64 0.4712 1.414
  * lon          (lon) float64 31.25
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds    (time, bnds) object ...
    lat_bnds     (lat, bnds) float64 0.0 0.9424 0.9424 1.885
    lon_bnds     (lon, bnds) float64 ...
    pr           (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
Attributes: (12/48)
    Conventions:            CF-1.7 CMIP-6.2
    activity_id:            ScenarioMIP
    branch_method:          standard
    branch_time_in_child:   60225.0
    branch_time_in_parent:  60225.0
    comment:                none
                    ...
    title:                  CMCC-ESM2 output prepared for CMIP6
    variable_id:            pr
    variant_label:          r1i1p1f1
    license:                CMIP6 model data produced by CMCC is licensed und...
    cmor_version:           3.6.0
    tracking_id:            hdl:21.14100/0c6732f7-2cdd-4296-99a0-7952b7ca911e
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to clip the whole dataset, but only the `pr` data var can be clipped. This is because it is the only one with both x and y dimensions. This should work:

```py
dset_shp = dset.pr.rio.clip(shp.geometry, shp.crs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I get the following error: NoDataInBounds: No data found in bounds. Data variable: pr.

Comment: That means that there was no data when you performed the clip operation.

Comment: There seems to be data though.. When I print dset.pr this is what I get:

array([[[7.368938e-07],
...
        [1.653116e-07]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) object 2021-01-01 12:00:00 ... 2025-12-31 12:00:00
  * lat      (lat) float64 0.4712 1.414
  * lon      (lon) float64 31.25

Comment: I thought it might had something to do with the size of the polygon compared to the pixel, since the pixels are much larger than the polygon. However, adding all_touched = True does not help. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390777/no-data-found-in-bounds-using-rioxarray-to-clip-geotiff-to-shapefile

Comment: Might be that the data in the cell is filled with the no data value.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to access the shp file values and specify the `drop` and `invert` kwargs:

```py
dset_shp = dset.rio.clip(shp.geometry.values, shp.crs, drop=False, invert=False)
```

Following [examples in rioxarray documentation](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html).